# Color Change in Bolded Text for Calender control

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm developing an app using Month calendar control of C#.net .

I am wondering how I can change the fore color of  selected/bolded text in the calendar Month.

Comment: What do you mean with the "bolded text". Which text is in bold ?

Comment: Date which one that i was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `SelectedDayStyle` property of your control.

An example can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_calendar_selecteddaystyle.asp)

Comment: sorry to say, Its Static Application .

Comment: What do you mean with "Static Application" ?

Comment: I don't know a quick solution to this. Have a look at [this Codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MonthCalendar.aspx). It might help you further. There is source code you can download